# How to add grey area behind boxplots without affecting boxplot colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am doing a boxplot, where I would like to add a grey zone behind my boxplots. However, when I do that, the boxplots are getting grey instead of black (see image below).
What can I do to keep the grey area behind the boxplots and not affect their color (ie. black in this case)?

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid",
        font_scale = 1.5)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))

min_value = 7*0.27
max_value = 7*1.77

# Fill the area between the minimum and maximum lines with grey on ax1
ax1.fill_betweenx([min_value, max_value], -0.5, 9.5, color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)

# Create a second axis (ax2) for the boxplots on top of ax1
ax2 = sns.boxplot(data=Data,
            x="Diet type", 
            y="GW", 
            #hue="Diet",
            #whis = 0,
            width = 0.3,
            color = "black",
            showmeans = True,
            meanprops={"marker":"o",
                       "markerfacecolor":"red", 
                       "markeredgecolor":"black",
                      "markersize":"6"},
            ax = ax1,
            zorder = 1
            )

# Fill the area between the minimum and maximum lines with grey
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax2.set_ylabel("Global Warming (kg CO2e/p/week)")
ax2.set_xlabel("")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 7*5.2)

plt.axhline(y=7*1.77, color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=7*0.81, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=7*0.27, color='black', linestyle='-')
```

I tried to split them in two axes and define the order of the boxplots to be one top of the grey zone, but I can't make it work.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Set the `zorder=0` when you call `ax1.fill_betweenx(...)` and keep the `zorder=1` in `ax2`. Explicitly defining the zorder for both axes solves the problem!

[image: example with grey background]

#### Code

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid",
        font_scale = 1.5)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))

min_value = 7*0.27
max_value = 7*1.77

# Fill the area between the minimum and maximum lines with grey on ax1
ax1.fill_betweenx([min_value, max_value], -0.5, 9.5, color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5, zorder=0)

# Create a second axis (ax2) for the boxplots on top of ax1
ax2 = sns.boxplot(data=Data,
            x="Diet type", 
            y="GW", 
            #hue="Diet",
            #whis = 0,
            width = 0.3,
            color = "black",
            showmeans = True,
            meanprops={"marker":"o",
                       "markerfacecolor":"red", 
                       "markeredgecolor":"black",
                      "markersize":"6"},
            ax = ax1,
            zorder = 1
            )

# Fill the area between the minimum and maximum lines with grey
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax2.set_ylabel("Global Warming (kg CO2e/p/week)")
ax2.set_xlabel("")
ax2.set_ylim(0, 7*5.2)

plt.axhline(y=7*1.77, color='black', linestyle='-')
plt.axhline(y=7*0.81, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=7*0.27, color='black', linestyle='-')
```